# How to return an array from a function to the main script

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote the following code in order to find the newest files added in three different folders. I have stored the directories of the folders in an array called path. I also store the names of the newest files in another array.

```
$path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check";
$path[1] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check2";
$path[2] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check3";

for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){

$path_last = $path[$i]; // set the path
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

 $d = dir($path_last);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path_last}/{$entry}";
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
$latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
$latest_filename = $entry;
$array[$i] = $latest_filename ; // assign the names of the latest files in an array.
   }
  }
```

Everything works fine but now I try to put the same code in a function and call it in my main script. I use this code in order to call it:

```
   include 'last_file.php'; // Include the function last_file
   $last_file = last_file();  // assign to the function a variable and call the function
```

I am not sure if this is correct. What I want to do is to return the array in my main script .. 
I hope it's clear here what I am trying to explain.
Thanks
D.

This is the last_file function:

```
    function last_file(){

        for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){

     $path_last = $path[$i]; // set the path
      $latest_ctime = 0;
       $latest_filename = '';    

      $d = dir($path_last);
     while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      $filepath = "{$path_last}/{$entry}";
      // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
       if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
        $latest_filename = $entry;
     $array[$i] = $latest_filename ; // assign the names of the latest files in an   array.
        }
      }

    return $array;

      }//end loop
      }//end function
```

Comment: Show your last_file function. You may just need to return the array.

Comment: The last line of your function should be `return $array;` assuming `$array` is the one you wish to return.

Comment: After seeing your code - move that `return $array;` _outside the loop_, before the function's closing `}`

Comment: Thanx. I did it. The problem is that I don't know how to call the array in my main source code. For example, how can I have access of array[0] somewhere in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it in a function, you need to return it like so.

```
function func_name()
{
$path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check";
$path[1] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check2";
$path[2] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check3";

for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){

$path_last = $path[$i]; // set the path
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

 $d = dir($path_last);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path_last}/{$entry}";
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
$latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
$latest_filename = $entry;
$array[$i] = $latest_filename ; // assign the names of the latest files in an array.
return $array;
}
```

Then when you call that function and assign it to a variable you will get the contents of $array

```
$contentsFromFunction = func_name();
```

Comment: I do this but then in the main source how can I use the array for something like thi:                                         $file_path[0] = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/".$array[0];

Comment: Thanx. I did it. The problem is that I don't know how to call the array in my main source code. For example, how can I have access of array[0] somewhere in my script?

Comment: In my example, you would then call $contentsFromFunction[0]

So when you call $contentsFromFunction = func_name();

Whatever was in $array in the function func_name() is now in $contentsFromFunction.

Comment: I assign the function like this:    $last_file = last_file();        And then I want to use the array value like this:    $file_path = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_test/check/".$last_file[0];             But it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: What's in the $last_file variable? You can find out using var_dump($last_file);

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know what's going on. It doesn't give me any result. If I copy the function script in my main script it works fine but when I try to put it in a separate function it doesn't work.

Comment: GOD. I had a really stupid mistake! I had assigned some values outside my function and php couldn't see them! Thanx a lot. Now it works perfect! Thanx for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing a *function* with a *file*.  Your code is put in *files*.  Within those files, you can define *functions*:

```
<?php
// This is inside last_file.php

function someFunction {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

To use `someFunction()` in another file, you first include `last_file.php` and then call `someFunction()`:

```
<?php
// This is inside some other file.

include 'last_file.php';

someFunction();
```